# RUN@Cloud consistently throws me out during a heavy operation

Tags: cloudbees

I'm using a large app instance to run a basic java web application (GWT + Spring). There's an expensive operation within my application (report) which takes a long time to execute.

I've tried running it with the cloudbees SDK on my local machine with similar settings as it would be on the cloud and it seems to function just fine. It runs in about 3-4 minutes.

On the cloud, it seems to be taking longer. The problem isn't the fact that it takes long. What happens in that cloudbees terminates the session after 5 minutes and gives me an error in my browser saying 'Unable to connect to server. Please contact your administrator'. A report which doesn't take as long runs just fine. My application has a session timeout of 30 minutes, so that isn't a problem either.

What could possibly be going wrong? Is it something to do with cloudbees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be due to proxy buffering of your request through the routing layer (revproxy) - so it most likely isn't a session timeout - but the http connection getting cut.

You can either set proxyBuffering=false via the bees CLI command (eg when you deploy the app) - this will ensure longer running connections can work.

Ideally, however, you could change the app slightly to return to the browser with some token which you can poll with to get completion status, as even with a connection that lasts that long, over the internet it may provide a bad experience vs locally.

Comment: It's also worthwhile logging how long it is before the time-out occurs.  If it's always a fixed amount of time, then there may be a timeout occurring in the stack (as opposed to the "internet" killing your connection). The stack includes both your application and components within the CloudBees system.

Comment: Seems to solve my issue. This will definitely be a quick fix until we can get to optimizing and speeding up the operation so that it will never actually take this long. Thanks.